# Raspberry Pi Access Control System

Tags: rfid, kiosk

I want to be able to have a Raspberry Pi monitor when people "Check In" and "Check Out" of a building. The idea would be that when they enter the building they would enter a code, or maybe scan an rfid tag or barcode, and it would log the time until they scan it again as they leave. What is the best way to do this? It would ideally not require the user to navigate menus or anything, and provide an easy way to see how long each user was in the building.

Comment: Unfortunately this site isn't the best place for this type of question. There are many thousands of solutions, which doesn't allow anyone to post a definitive answer. You might have better luck asking this on the [raspberrypi.org forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/), where open ended discussion is encouraged, or there's some useful stuff in this site's [help centre](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) if you'd like to try to focus your question a little.

Comment: This site is not a discussion forum -- please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) again and pay attention to the Get answers to practical, detailed questions part. *I am looking for the most stable and low maintenance solution.* furthermore looks to me like the purchase of an existing solution is the right way to go (which in turn renders the question off-topic as shopping reccomendation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an excellent application for RFID cards.  RFID scanners are very cheap.  When an RFID card or key fob is brought into proximity of the scanner, the scanner will record/register its arrival.  Each RFID card can have its own unique ID and can also be programmed to contain a small amount of additional information.

The most popular RFID scanner is the MFRC522 which can be bought for a few dollars.  There are also many excellent tutorials and samples for working with this sensor.  Many are also specific to the Pi.

Some staring links might include:

[How to use RFID-RC522](http://raspmer.blogspot.com/2015/07/how-to-use-rfid-rc522-on-raspbian.html)

There is also an instructables that sounds very much like what you want to achieve.  See:

[Attendance system using Raspberry Pi and NFC Tag reader](http://www.instructables.com/id/Attendance-system-using-Raspberry-Pi-and-NFC-Tag-r/?ALLSTEPS)

Comment: I am asking about the software, I intend to use either an HID compliant keypad or and HID barcode scanner or HID RFID scanner. I am mostly wondering how to handle the logging of the entries and exits.

Comment: Let us assume a person identifies themselves at time T1 and then later re-identifies themselves at T2.  You now have two events having occurred.  These can be recorded to a database, published (eg. using MQTT), written to a log file and such ... are you looking for pre-written software to accomplish this task?

Comment: I am looking for the most stable and low maintenance solution. It is to be used in a business environment so while I will be able to fix it if something goes wrong, it would be ideal for it to just work.